Selenium How to Wait Page Loading
We have a ticket system, and I want to automate some parts of it. I implemented a solution, but it's not working properly. I need to wait for the values of the dropdown menus, and you can see how the page refreshes itself. This is problematic because the page refreshes 3-4 times, causing the code to fail.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id="select2-SubReason-results"]/li[15] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

The options of the second dropdown menu you see in the video are fetched from the server via a POST request after a selection is made from the first dropdown menu. Selenium attempts to open the second dropdown menu before the data has loaded, which causes it to wait with the line WebElement optionWebElement = waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(optionToSelect))); and results in an error due to the empty menu. I need to open the second dropdown menu only after the data has been loaded, or repeatedly try to open and close the menu in a loop until the data is loaded.
There's a video (I am controlling the page in the video, also blurred for privacy): https://streamable.com/p47d93
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import Enums.*;

class Main {
    private static WebDriver chromeDriver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/<User>/Desktop/Selenium/ChromeDriver-win64/ChromeDriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setBinary("C:/Users/<User>/Desktop/Selenium/Chrome-win64/Chrome.exe");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/<User>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome for Testing/User Data");

        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        chromeDriver.get("Removed for privacy");
        
        selectItem(Elements.Application.xPath, Applications.Computer.xPath, 0);
        selectItem(Elements.SubReason.xPath, SubReasons.Printer.xPath, 1);
    }

    public static void sendKeys(String textareaElement, String keysToSend) { 
        WebDriverWait waitElement = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
        waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(textareaElement)));

        WebElement webElement = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(textareaElement));
        webElement.sendKeys(keysToSend);
    }

    public static void selectItem(String selectElement, String optionToSelect, int isLoadingExpected) throws Exception {
        WebDriverWait waitElement = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));

        if (isLoadingExpected == 1) {
            waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("loading")));
            waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("loading")));
        }

        WebElement selectWebElement = waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(selectElement)));
        selectWebElement.click();

        WebElement optionWebElement = waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(optionToSelect)));
        optionWebElement.click();
    }
}


To handle this, you can implement a more robust waiting mechanism to ensure the data is loaded before interacting with the dropdown.
This code introduces a loop that keeps trying to click the option until it becomes clickable, with a short sleep interval between attempts. This should help ensure that the second dropdown menu is only interacted with once the data is fully loaded.
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import Enums.*;

class Main {
    private static WebDriver chromeDriver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/<User>/Desktop/Selenium/ChromeDriver-win64/ChromeDriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setBinary("C:/Users/<User>/Desktop/Selenium/Chrome-win64/Chrome.exe");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/<User>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome for Testing/User Data");

        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        chromeDriver.get("Removed for privacy");
        
        selectItem(Elements.Application.xPath, Applications.Computer.xPath, 0);
        selectItem(Elements.SubReason.xPath, SubReasons.Printer.xPath, 1);
    }

    public static void sendKeys(String textareaElement, String keysToSend) { 
        WebDriverWait waitElement = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
        waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(textareaElement)));

        WebElement webElement = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(textareaElement));
        webElement.sendKeys(keysToSend);
    }

    public static void selectItem(String selectElement, String optionToSelect, int isLoadingExpected) throws Exception {
        WebDriverWait waitElement = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        if (isLoadingExpected == 1) {
            waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("loading")));
            waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("loading")));
        }

        WebElement selectWebElement = waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(selectElement)));
        selectWebElement.click();

        boolean optionLoaded = false;
        while (!optionLoaded) {
            try {
                WebElement optionWebElement = waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(optionToSelect)));
                optionWebElement.click();
                optionLoaded = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Option not loaded yet, retry
                Thread.sleep(500);
                selectWebElement.click(); // Reopen the dropdown
            }
        }
    }
}

